# Does LanguageTool Java API have "useless" dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, languagetool

I want to use [LanguageTool's Java API](http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api) for spell checking hence I add its dependency into my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.languagetool</groupId>
  <artifactId>language-en</artifactId>
  <version>4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

For some reason it downloads 40MB `jar` dependencies which looks suspicious. Here is a screen shot with all of them:

[image]

But if we go to [maven central repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.languagetool/language-en/4.7), its `.jar` is only **4.7MB**.

After that I noticed the `scala-compiler.jar` which is about **20MB**, and I tried to exclude it:

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

Then I ran my `main` and everything ran fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JLanguageTool lang = new JLanguageTool(new AmericanEnglish());
    List<RuleMatch> matches = lang.check("This is a speling errorr.");
    for (RuleMatch match : matches)
    {
        System.out.println(match.getSuggestedReplacements());
    }
}
```

So I took sometime and start excluding more and more dependencies, and in some of them I was getting `ClassNotFoundException`, which is fine because it makes sense if `language-tool` uses some of them. But what about the non-used ones? Is there by any chance used, but with my code does not use any class of them, so I avoid getting a `ClassNotFoundException`?

My question is why does it download dependencies that are not being used. Is there a way to find out which of them are useless so I can exclude them?

In order to make sure that they can be considered as "useless" I even build my jar (+with dependencies) and it seems that the program runs without problem. I have only one class inside with the code snippet above. This is the whole `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>anothertest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>test.Re</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.languagetool</groupId>
            <artifactId>language-en</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>edu.berkeley.nlp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>berkeleylm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
                    <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>txw2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.optimaize.languagedetector</groupId>
                    <artifactId>language-detector</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.esotericsoftware.kryo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: i have not used this library yet, but the list of dependencies looks nice. Do you know Prouard?

Comment: @swolf If you mean `Proguard`, yes. Do you think is worth to give it a try in order to find the "useless" ones?

Comment: if the application size is important for you, then yes, else no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer this question more generally:

Maven builds the list of all dependencies by going transitively through the dependency tree, collect every dependency and then doing dependency mediation (if you find more than one version of an artifact).

This is a coarse way to gather dependencies which more or less guarantees that you have everything you need -- but often you have a lot more.

Why is that?

First of all, during runtime you usually only call a subset of the defined classes so it can easily happen that some parts of the application (like some dependencies) are never touched. In many cases it would even be possible to statically prove that a certain dependency can never be called through the normal chains because e.g. you only use one class `A` of a dependency `a.jar`, and `a.jar` depends on `b.jar` but needs it only for things unrelated to `A`.

But: There are various ways a jar *may* be necessary during runtime which are difficult to detect. This includes different types of dependency injection, especially on an application server.

Comment: With other words, my assumption that these jars may be used and useful, but my code snippet won't be harmed if they are not there, is correct? However, what choices do I have? Having 25-30MB of "deployment overhead" does not sound good. Maybe I should stay with `exclusions`, spend some time testing to see if any `ClassNotFound` takes place...

Comment: You can write a lot of unit tests and see if they work if you exclude some of the dependencies.